# Is there another way to solve this forEach problem using map, filter, reduce...?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

If i have two arrays of objects like these two

```
const x = [{id: 1, a: 5}, {id: 2, a:10}, {id: 3, a: 12}];

const y = [{id: 4, a: 0}, {id: 2, a: 0}, {id: 3, a: 0}];
```

The output should be a new array represents `y` 
but with some modifications, if an item in y has an `id` matches an item in x, `a` value should be the same as x, so the output should be

```
[{id: 4, a: 0}, {id: 2, a: 10}, {id: 3, a: 12}]
```

This is my solution

```
const z = [...y];
z.forEach(el => x.map(ele =>  el.a = el.id === ele.id ? ele.a : el.a));
```

This is a simple implementation of what i am doing in a project, i care about performance and i see the step of cloning the array `z = [...y]` may be expensive, so i am looking for a solution using functions that return a new array `map`, `filter`, `reduce`...,

I tried nested `map` and `filter`, `find` ... but i ended with complex solutions, so are there another solutions that would be more performant and simple in same time?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over `x` for each value of `y` you can create a xObj from `x` by single iteration and in the loop over `y` just check if it's exist in the xObj `(constant lookup O(1) )` if yes then update it otherwise use the existing value.

```
const x = [{id: 1, a: 5}, {id: 2, a:10}, {id: 3, a: 12}];

const y = [{id: 4, a: 0}, {id: 2, a: 0}, {id: 3, a: 0}];

var xObj = {};

x.forEach(function(val){
  xObj[val.id] = val.a;
});

const newY = y.reduce(function(o,i){
    if(xObj.hasOwnProperty(i.id)){
     i.a = xObj[i.id];
  }
  o.push(i);
  return o;
},[]);

console.log(newY);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a problem like this you should care far *less* about the computational expense of creating a new array, and far *more* about the Big O expense of running through multiple arrays multiple times. Both your solution and the other one posted by @NitishNarang appear to be O(n^2) because as your arrays become larger, the number of steps required to solve increases exponentially.

Personally I would simply create a new `Map()` and go through each item one by one, adding it to the `Map()` only if the value of `a` corresponding to that ID is larger than the currently stored one. It's basically a slightly more complicated sorting exercise except with unique ID values thrown in.

```
const x = [{id: 1, a: 5}, {id: 2, a:10}, {id: 3, a: 12}];
const y = [{id: 4, a: 0}, {id: 2, a: 0}, {id: 3, a: 0}];
const myMap = new Map();
for (const ea of x) {
  if (!myMap.has(ea.id) || ea.a >= myMap.get(ea.id).a) {
    myMap.set(ea.id, ea);
  }
}
for (const ea of y) {
  if (!myMap.has(ea.id) || ea.a >= myMap.get(ea.id).a) {
    myMap.set(ea.id, ea);
  }
}
const result = [...myMap.values()];
```

This solution is O(n), i.e. it's linear, meaning that if you add 10 or 100 or 1000 more items to the array `x` or `y` or both, it will only add that many more steps to running the solution instead of 10^2 or 100^2 or 1000^2 because you have to check every single item in each array against every other item in the other array (like you do with your original solution.)

Edit: as @SZenC pointed out, the above solution is not quite correct as it combines both arrays. In order to selectively match items only if they originally exist in array `y`, simply iterate over `y` first, and then only replace values when iterating over `x` if they are already present in the map:

```
const x = [{id: 1, a: 5}, {id: 2, a:10}, {id: 3, a: 12}];
const y = [{id: 4, a: 0}, {id: 2, a: 0}, {id: 3, a: 0}];
const myMap = new Map();
for (const ea of y) {
  if (!myMap.has(ea.id) || ea.a >= myMap.get(ea.id).a) {
    myMap.set(ea.id, ea);
  }
}
for (const ea of x) {
  if (myMap.has(ea.id) && ea.a >= myMap.get(ea.id).a) {
    myMap.set(ea.id, ea);
  }
}
const result = [...myMap.values()];
```

Comment: This is a more complex solution, but i loved this one, thanks

Comment: More lines of code doesn't necessarily mean "complex." Good code is easy to follow and efficient, even if that means it taking up a little more space. Sometimes the "clever" one-line solution is actually incredibly inefficient and hard to decipher. :)

Comment: It is indeed computationally better, but the `result` value is incorrect as it contains all ids. OP only asked for those present in `y`

Comment: @SZenC You are right. I've updated my answer to reflect the original question.

Comment: @jered thanks for drawing my attention to this, you mean one line solution better to be avoided???

Answer (score 1):

Use `Set` to store the `ids` available in `x` array and use `map` over `y` array to check whether `y's` `id` exists in the `Set` or not.

```js
const x = [{id: 1, a: 5}, {id: 2, a:10}, {id: 3, a: 12}];

const y = [{id: 4, a: 0}, {id: 2, a: 0}, {id: 3, a: 0}];

const mapped = Object.values(x).reduce((acc, {id}) => {
  acc.add(id)
  return acc;
}, new Set());

const result = y.map((obj, index) => mapped.has(obj.id) ? {...obj, a: x[index].a} : obj);

console.log(result);
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It uses "[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)" and "[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)"

```js
const x = [{id: 1, a: 5}, {id: 2, a:10}, {id: 3, a: 12}];

const y = [{id: 4, a: 0}, {id: 2, a: 0}, {id: 3, a: 0}];

const result = y.map(yData => (xResult = x.find(xData => xData.id == yData.id), xResult && { ...yData, a: xResult.a } || yData))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: sorry bro but there is an issue, this replaces the object in y by the one in x!!!, i do not need that, i need the same item with just changed value of a

Comment: "Simple" because it uses a single line to solve, but extremely computationally expensive because it is O(n^2). You really don't want to be doing an `Array.find()` of one array from inside of another array's `Array.map()`...

Comment: Edited solution to cater @SaherElgendy only "a" property change

Comment: Correct @jered, but I believe it all depends upon how big data being used by Saher. If it is in hundreds of records then we may see a time difference, but if its relatively small then hardly any time difference is noticed

Comment: But you are correct given computation difference you are mentioning.